# Parse SQL geometry Value to Arcpy Python geometry object

Tags: arcpy, sql, enterprise-geodatabase, geometry, import

I'm trying to get a multiPolgon value returned from an SQL query (SQL Server 2014) to a an Arcpy Geometry Object. I know this is very easy I just am missing something.Whats confusing is this is a Native ESRI Enterprise Geodatabase (ArcGIS 10.7.1) and this is the normal SHAPE field that all feature classes have.

I can do very easily using the Cursor object and the SHAPE@ token associated with the data access module however the query performance on this takes about 4 hours to run due to remote access on very choked pipe. Where as the SQL direct query takes about 30 Seconds to run.

Basically I need the result from SQL Query below for field 4 or 5 or what ever I have to CAST it as to feed into arcpy.Geometry('POLYGON', something from the query)

```
SELECT
    ITEMS.{feild_0},
    ITEMS.{feild_1},
    ITEMS.{feild_2},
    ITEMS.{feild_3},
    CAST(ITEMS.{feild_4} AS geometry), 
    CAST(ITEMS.{feild_4} AS nvarchar(max)),  
    ITEMS.{feild_6}
FROM
    {user_id}.{table_id} AS ITEMS

WHERE
    {sql_query}
ORDER BY '{feild_0}';
```

Comment: ArcGIS might be able to read the geometry natively, but if not, then you could use Well-Known Text (WKT) or Well-Known Binary (WKB).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Vince was the one that got me the answer, the return of the nvarchar(max) feeding into the arcpy.FomWKT

```
SELECT
    ITEMS.{feild_0},
    ITEMS.{feild_1},
    ITEMS.{feild_2},
    ITEMS.{feild_3},
    ITEMS.{feild_4}, 
    CAST(ITEMS.{feild_5} AS nvarchar(max)),  
    ITEMS.{feild_6}
FROM
    {user_id}.{table_id} AS ITEMS

WHERE
    {sql_query}
ORDER BY '{feild_0}';
```

Pushing the relevant query result

```
row_geometry = arcpy.FromWKT(row.field_5)
```

returns `<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x000000000A3BE058>`